# Spark Streaming textFileStream not supporting wildcards

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I setup a simple test to stream text files from S3 and got it to work when I tried something like

```
val input = ssc.textFileStream("s3n://mybucket/2015/04/03/")
```

and in the bucket I would have log files go in there and everything would work fine.

But if their was a subfolder, it would not find any files that got put into the subfolder (and yes, I am aware that hdfs doesn't actually use a folder structure)

```
val input = ssc.textFileStream("s3n://mybucket/2015/04/")
```

So, I tried to simply do wildcards like I have done before with a standard spark application

```
val input = ssc.textFileStream("s3n://mybucket/2015/04/*")
```

But when I try this it throws an error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File s3n://mybucket/2015/04/* does not exist.
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.listStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:506)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1483)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1523)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.findNewFiles(FileInputDStream.scala:176)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.compute(FileInputDStream.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:300)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:299)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:287)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
.....
```

I know for a fact that you can use wildcards when reading fileInput for a standard spark applications but it appears that when doing streaming input, it doesn't do that nor does it automatically process files in subfolders.  Is there something I'm missing here??

Ultimately what I need is a streaming job to be running 24/7 that will be monitoring an S3 bucket that has logs placed in it by date

So something like

```
s3n://mybucket/<YEAR>/<MONTH>/<DAY>/<LogfileName>
```

Is there any way to hand it the top most folder and it automatically read files that show up in any folder (cause obviously the date will increase every day)?

EDIT

So upon digging into the documentation at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources it states that nested directories are not supported.

Can anyone shed some light as to why this is the case?

Also, since my files will be nested based upon their date, what would be a good way of solving this problem in my streaming application?  It's a little complicated since the logs take a few minutes to get written to S3 and so the last file being written for the day could be written in the previous day's folder even though we're a few minutes into the new day.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if s3 support wildcards...

Comment: It most certainly does.  My jobs have been using wildcards for the past 8 months.  Also, just for a sanity check I just ran a job with wildcard input, worked fine.

I did notice that it's a little picky about requiring that you don't do something like

    s3n://mybucket/2015/04*

as says that

    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not a file: s3n://mybucket/2015/04/01

Which makes sense as it isn't a file

But if you do

    s3n://mybucket/2015/04/*

It correctly parses all the files in the days sub folders....
This kind of feels like a bug to me.

Comment: I'm gonna vote up the question. I remember having a similar problem but I don't recall how I have solved it.

Comment: I appreciate it.  This certainly sounds like a common implementation.

Answer (score 7):

Some "ugly but working solution" can be created by extending FileInputDStream.
Writing `sc.textFileStream(d)` is equivalent to

```
new FileInputDStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](streamingContext, d).map(_._2.toString)
```

You can create CustomFileInputDStream that will extend FileInputDStream. The custom class will copy the compute method from the FileInputDStream class and adjust the findNewFiles method to your needs.

changing findNewFiles method from:

```
 private def findNewFiles(currentTime: Long): Array[String] = {
    try {
      lastNewFileFindingTime = clock.getTimeMillis()

  // Calculate ignore threshold
  val modTimeIgnoreThreshold = math.max(
    initialModTimeIgnoreThreshold,   // initial threshold based on newFilesOnly setting
    currentTime - durationToRemember.milliseconds  // trailing end of the remember window
  )
  logDebug(s"Getting new files for time $currentTime, " +
    s"ignoring files older than $modTimeIgnoreThreshold")
  val filter = new PathFilter {
    def accept(path: Path): Boolean = isNewFile(path, currentTime, modTimeIgnoreThreshold)
  }
  val newFiles = fs.listStatus(directoryPath, filter).map(_.getPath.toString)
  val timeTaken = clock.getTimeMillis() - lastNewFileFindingTime
  logInfo("Finding new files took " + timeTaken + " ms")
  logDebug("# cached file times = " + fileToModTime.size)
  if (timeTaken > slideDuration.milliseconds) {
    logWarning(
      "Time taken to find new files exceeds the batch size. " +
        "Consider increasing the batch size or reducing the number of " +
        "files in the monitored directory."
    )
  }
  newFiles
} catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    logWarning("Error finding new files", e)
    reset()
    Array.empty
}
```

}

to:

```
  private def findNewFiles(currentTime: Long): Array[String] = {
    try {
      lastNewFileFindingTime = clock.getTimeMillis()

      // Calculate ignore threshold
      val modTimeIgnoreThreshold = math.max(
        initialModTimeIgnoreThreshold,   // initial threshold based on newFilesOnly setting
        currentTime - durationToRemember.milliseconds  // trailing end of the remember window
      )
      logDebug(s"Getting new files for time $currentTime, " +
        s"ignoring files older than $modTimeIgnoreThreshold")
      val filter = new PathFilter {
        def accept(path: Path): Boolean = isNewFile(path, currentTime, modTimeIgnoreThreshold)
      }
      val directories = fs.listStatus(directoryPath).filter(_.isDirectory)
      val newFiles = ArrayBuffer[FileStatus]()

      directories.foreach(directory => newFiles.append(fs.listStatus(directory.getPath, filter) : _*))

      val timeTaken = clock.getTimeMillis() - lastNewFileFindingTime
      logInfo("Finding new files took " + timeTaken + " ms")
      logDebug("# cached file times = " + fileToModTime.size)
      if (timeTaken > slideDuration.milliseconds) {
        logWarning(
          "Time taken to find new files exceeds the batch size. " +
            "Consider increasing the batch size or reducing the number of " +
            "files in the monitored directory."
        )
      }
      newFiles.map(_.getPath.toString).toArray
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        logWarning("Error finding new files", e)
        reset()
        Array.empty
    }
  }
```

will check for files in all first degree sub folders, you can adjust it to use the batch timestamp in order to access the relevant "subdirectories".

I created the CustomFileInputDStream as I mentioned and activated it by calling:

```
new CustomFileInputDStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](streamingContext, d).map(_._2.toString)
```

It seems to behave us expected.

When I write solution like this I must add some points for consideration:

- You are breaking Spark encapsulation and creating a custom class that you would have to support solely as time pass.
- I believe that solution like this is the last resort. If your use case can be implemented by different way, it is usually better to avoid solution like this.
- If you will have a lot of "subdirectories" on S3 and would check each one of them it will cost you.
- It will be very interesting to understand if Databricks doesn't support nested files just because of possible performance penalty or not, maybe there is a deeper reason I haven't thought about.

Comment: I have a similar use case and I'm thinking of going down this path if i don't find an alternate. I have date partitioned sub folders using format YYYY-MM-DD-HH. Every hour a new folder is created and files are uploaded into it. So I won't necessarily have to scan all subfolder(only last three) and will not hit performance issues. I'm more worried about maintainability of such code and state management for restarts (which hour folder+file was last scanned, etc). See if you can share your thoughts on this or even code that worked for your custom FileDstream.

Comment: If you are using checkpoint directory with your stream, then when you restart you application you will first reschedule all the batches that should have been executing during application down time. e.g If your streaming interval is 1 minute, and your application is going down at 10:00 and back up at 10:30, when it will be up the app will try to execute the batch of 10:01, 10:02 etc.
Now if you implement a findNewFiles(currentTime) in a way that the folders you scan are derived from the currentTime, you will be able to scan the "right" files after restarts.

Comment: Please note that currentTime is not actually CURRENT time, it is the time of the batch.

The only problem I can think of in that approach is that if your files are not immutable. e.g you write some data to file A at 10:10 and overwrite this data at 10:20, then if your application was down between 10:10-10:20 you will lose the first writing to A. It is indeed a problem, but I'm not familiar with many organizations that work with mutable files in such scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for you comments! We ended up using AWS lambda as a first step to process files as they land in S3.

Answer (score 0):

we had same problem. we joined sub folder names with comma.

```
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

try {        
    Date start = sdf.parse("2015/02/01");
    Date end = sdf.parse("2015/04/01");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(start);        

    while (calendar.getTime().before(end)) {
        paths.add("s3n://mybucket/" + sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }                
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String joinedPaths = StringUtils.join(",", paths.toArray(new String[paths.size()]));
val input = ssc.textFileStream(joinedPaths);
```

I hope that in this way your problem is solved.

Comment: Cool. How you deal with bigger end dates? by compiling and relaunching the program? Or am I missing something?