# Is there a way to stream files from nested directories in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I see in the docs that nested directories are not supported by Spark's `StreamingContext.fileStream()` stream. Has anyone found any sort of **workaround** for this?

```
 streamingContext.fileStream[KeyClass, ValueClass, InputFormatClass](dataDirectory)
```

Link: [Streaming-Programming-guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers)

[Link to Issue SPARK-1795](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/537)

[Link to Issue SPARK-3586](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3586)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426246/spark-streaming-textfilestream-not-supporting-wildcards , this might help.