# Spark streaming from multiple folder

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have the exact same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426246/spark-streaming-textfilestream-not-supporting-wildcards). I was not able to comment there as I didn't have enough reputation in stackoverflow. So I'm posting a duplicate. Not sure if there is a way around it.

The answer given there doesn't work. textFileStream() doesn't take comma separated folder list.

```
16/02/24 11:01:40 WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/shared/data/2016-01-22-05/,file:/shared/data/2016-01-22-06 does not exist
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:376)
```

This is what I have so far

```
val folderList = makeAListOfFoldersToWatch()
val dstreamsList = folderList.map(ssc.textFileStream(_))
val lines = ssc.union(dstreamsList)
lines.foreachRDD( rdd => {
```

This solution works on a fixed folder list. The use case here is to have S3 folders per hour in YYYY-MM-DD-HH format. New folder is created every hour. **Is there a way to keep folder list updated in a long running streaming job?** Any other way to solve this?