# Update Spark Streaming Variable During Execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job that is reading ELB logs from an S3 directory, 
`s3://elb-data/2017-04-17/`,
parsing them and converting them to ORC, and then storing them in a new directory: `s3://parsed-data/2017-04-17/`. Here is my code to do that:

```
val streamContext = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(30))
val rawLogFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd/")
val rawLogDate = rawLogFormat.format(new java.util.Date())
val filepath = args(0) + rawLogDate
val parsedLog = streamContext.textFileStream(filepath)

val jsonRows = parsedLog.mapPartitions(lines => {
  val txfm = new LogLine2Json
  lines.map(line =>
    try{
      txfm.parseLine(line)
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception => {println(line); "";}
    }
  )
})
```

At the beginning of a new day, AWS automatically puts logs into a new directory, which I'd like my streaming job to reference. (`s3://elb-logs/2017-04-18/`) However, I noticed that once my job got to the end of the 04/17 data, it just stopped seeing new files. Is there a way to update this variable while the code is executing? Or does this require that I submit a new job through `spark-submit`? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think your `filepath` stayed the same for your streaming job, it keeps parsing this same directory `s3://parsed-data/2017-04-17/`. You need to make it point to your root directory, which is `s3://parsed-data/` then if there's a new date `s3://parsed-data/2017-04-18/` it should be able to pick up the new data. Also see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426246/spark-streaming-textfilestream-not-supporting-wildcards) post.

Comment: My only question is whether I can change the location of my output accordingly? I need all data in `s3://elb-logs/2017-04-17/` to end up in `s3://parsed-logs/2017-04-17/` and for all data in `s3://elb-logs/2017-04-18/` to land in `s3://parsed-logs/2017-04-18/`, etc. Is this possible with the wildcard solution?